# Unable to start odoo 8 getting bootstrap 404

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I want to use eclipse for odoo development. So I had gone through this link, https://www.odoo.com/forum/how-to/developers-13/how-to-debug-odoo-in-eclipse-under-winows-36105
But odoo is not starting in the brower this is the partial traceback, I dont know why i am getting 404 error,after installation I only get this part of the website
[image]

```
2015-11-12 10:47:57,680 12928 INFO None werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [12/Nov/2015 10:47:57] "GET /web/database/manager HTTP/1.1" 200 -
2015-11-12 10:47:57,947 12928 INFO None werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [12/Nov/2015 10:47:57] "GET /web/static/src/css/full.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2015-11-12 10:47:58,489 12928 INFO None werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [12/Nov/2015 10:47:58] "GET /web/static/lib/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2015-11-12 10:47:58,545 12928 INFO None werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [12/Nov/2015 10:47:58] "GET /web/static/lib/cleditor/jquery.cleditor.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2015-11-12 10:47:58,599 12928 INFO None werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [12/Nov/2015 10:47:58] "GET /web/static/lib/jquery.ui.bootstrap/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.9.0.custom.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2015-11-12 10:47:58,654 12928 INFO None werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [12/Nov/2015 10:47:58] "GET /web/static/lib/jquery.ui.timepicker/css/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2015-11-12 10:47:58,710 12928 INFO None werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [12/Nov/2015 10:47:58] "GET /web/static/lib/jquery.textext/jquery.textext.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2015-11-12 10:47:58,799 12928 INFO None werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [12/Nov/2015 10:47:58] "GET /web/static/lib/select2/select2.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2015-11-12 10:47:58,931 12928 INFO None werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [12/Nov/2015 10:47:58] "GET /web/static/lib/jquery.ui.notify/css/ui.notify.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2015-11-12 10:47:58,987 12928 INFO None werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [12/Nov/2015 10:47:58] "GET /web/static/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2015-11-12 10:47:59,209 12928 INFO None werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [12/Nov/2015 10:47:59] "GET /web/static/src/css/base.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2015-11-12 10:47:59,210 12928 INFO None werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [12/Nov/2015 10:47:59] "GET /base/static/src/css/modules.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2015-11-12 10:47:59,305 12928 INFO None werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [12/Nov/2015 10:47:59] "GET /web/static/src/css/data_export.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2015-11-12 10:47:59,444 12928 INFO None werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [12/Nov/2015 10:47:59] "GET /web/static/lib/es5-shim/es5-shim.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2015-11-12 10:47:59,500 12928 INFO None werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [12/Nov/2015 10:47:59] "GET /web/static/lib/underscore/underscore.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2015-11-12 10:47:59,569 12928 INFO None werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [12/Nov/2015 10:47:59] "GET /web/static/lib/underscore.string/lib/underscore.string.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2015-11-12 10:47:59,809 12928 INFO None werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [12/Nov/2015 10:47:59] "GET /web/static/lib/datejs/globalization/en-US.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2015-11-12 10:47:59,887 12928 INFO None werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [12/Nov/2015 10:47:59] "GET /web/static/lib/jquery/jquery.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2015-11-12 10:48:00,005 12928 INFO None werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [12/Nov/2015 10:48:00] "GET /web/static/lib/spinjs/spin.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -
2015-11-12 10:48:00,207 12928 INFO None werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [12/Nov/2015 10:48:00] "GET /web/static/lib/jquery.placeholder/jquery.placeholder.js HTTP/1.1" 404 -


[options]
; This is the password that allows database operations:
; admin_passwd = admin
db_host = localhost
db_port = 5432
db_user = openpg
db_maxconn = 64
db_name = False
db_password = openpgpwd
xmlrpc = True
xmlrpc_port = 8069
xmlrpcs = True
xmlrpcs_port = 8071
addons_path = C:\Users\git\odoo\addons
```

Comment: could you add the details of openerp-server.conf file ?

Comment: hey i just added the configuration file can u find wht might be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)Check whether you have installed all python packages
2)Check whether addons path is correct in config file

Answer (score 0):

Just try this follow:

1. <kbd>Window</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and type `cmd` <kbd>enter</kbd>
2. Type `npm install -g less` <kbd>enter</kbd>
3. Type `npm install -g less-plugin-clean-css` <kbd>enter</kbd>